# Can I customize a CC BY-ND 4.0 theme and use it for a commercial website?

Tags: cc-by-nd

I would like to use a UI theme that is licensed as **Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International** for a commercial website after I edit and customize it.

Is there any copyright issue to be worried about?

Comment: It says NoDerivatives, so you're not allowed to customise  it!

Comment: Do you know what the license means? Did you read its summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. The copyright license does not allow you to make any changes.